# Install specific version of setuptools as a dependency of package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pyproject.toml

My package has setuptools in dependencies. I am trying to restrict the version of setuptools when installing my package.
The package has following restriction in setup.py:

```
setup(
    setup_requires=[
        'setuptools==50.2.0',
        'pip>=19,!=20.0,!=20.0.1,<21'
        ],
...
```

And it has the same restriction in pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools==50.2.0", "pip>=19,!=20.0,!=20.0.1,<21", "wheel"]  # PEP 508 specifications.
```

However, when installing my package with pip, it downloads the latest setuptools 50.3.0.

Why does it ignore the requirements? How can I make it not install the latest version?

Comment: I believe there is no use case where adding `setuptools` or `pip` to `setup_requires` makes sense, similarly there is no scenario I can think of where adding `pip` to `build-system.requires` is meaningful. On the other hand `setuptools` (and maybe `wheel`, but I have my doubts) in `build-system.requires` seems likethe right thing to do.

Comment: with python's environment like this: https://xkcd.com/1987/, you can do one thing many ways, depends on what your starting point is. adding `pip` to requirements probably doesn't make much sense, but I can see how some systems don't come with `setuptools` out of the box (especially older Python versions)

Comment: can you share the rest of your package, specifically what is your `install_requires`?

Comment: @AnthonySottile, ```install_requires=['cryptography>=2.4.2,<3', 'click>=7.0,<8', 'intelhex>=2.2.1,<3', 'python-jose>=3.0.1,<4', 'jsonschema>=3.0.0,<4', 'pyocd==0.27.3', 'cbor==1.0.0', 'imgtool==1.7.0a1'],```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem actually is. What do you mean exactly by "_it downloads the latest setuptools 50.3.0_", and why is that a problem? If _setuptools_ is a dependency (build-time, or install-time), then most likely it will be downloaded. And the version number _50.3.0_ seems to be in the range provided.

Comment: @sinoroc, thank you for pointing to the mistake. I have corrected it to 50.2.0.

Comment: OK. But that's what @rite2hhh has been already saying in his answer for a while: the version was in range. Now with the version range corrected (pinned to a single version number), there is the point made by Anthony Sottile, namely that there are _build-time_ and _run-time_ dependencies. Your question is only about _build_ dependencies (only restricts those), nothing about _install_. -- So the question remains what are you concerned about "_it downloads the latest setuptools 50.3.0_"? Are you concerned about _build-time_ or _run-time_?

Comment: @sinoroc, I want my package to be installed using a specific version of setuptools and then keep this version for the dependencies installation. Because if the latest version of setuptools is broken (this already happened twice), the dependencies will fail to install too. Seems the solution for me is to specify a version in pyproject.toml and specify the same version in the _install_requires_ section to keep it for dependencies. Also, keeping _setup_requires_ section in my case seems does nothing.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the whole situation. Would you mind rephrasing your whole question? State clearly the actual goal/issue first. And only second the solution that you have in mind. -- It seems to me like you are adding a pinned _setuptools_ as a dependency to your project only to fix the build of your project's dependencies? Does your project actually need _setuptools_ (at _build_ or _run_ time)?

Comment: pyproject.toml says what version of setuptools will be used for my package installation. However, if my _install_requires_ does not contain a specific setuptool version at the beginning, the latest version will be installed together with jsonschema package because it is specified in its dependencies (see the answer from Anthony Sottile). So if you want to keep this specific version, it should be at the beginning of the _install_requires_ list too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answers and comments I can make a conclusion.

To use a specific version of *setuptools* it is necessary to have it in both locations - in *pyproject.toml* and at the beginning of *install_requires* of *setup.py*.

The tool like *pip* will use the version from *pyproject.toml* to build the project. However, if there is any dependency that has the latest version of *setuptools* in its requirements, then the latest version will be used to install the dependency. Also, the environment will keep the version that was last installed.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're getting confused about build time (setup_requires / pyproject.toml build-system requires) and installed time (install_requires). at install time, you're getting unpinned setuptools because it's a transitive dependency without version restrictions

`setuptools` is being pulled in via a transitive dependency in `install_requires` (notably: `jsonschema`):

```
$ visualize-requirements t.txt
 cryptography>=2.4.2,<3
   - cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
     - pycparser
   - six>=1.4.1
 click>=7.0,<8
 intelhex<3,>=2.2.1
 python-jose<4,>=3.0.1
   - pyasn1
   - rsa
     - pyasn1>=0.1.3
   - ecdsa<0.15
     - six
   - six<2.0
 jsonschema<4,>=3.0.0
   - six>=1.11.0
   - attrs>=17.4.0
   - setuptools
   - pyrsistent>=0.14.0
 pyocd==0.27.3
   - intervaltree<4.0,>=3.0.2
     - sortedcontainers<3.0,>=2.0
   - pylink-square
     - six
     - psutil>=5.2.2
     - future
   - cmsis-pack-manager>=0.2.7
     - milksnake>=0.1.2
       - cffi>=1.6.0
         - pycparser
     - appdirs>=1.4
     - pyyaml>=3.12
   - pyelftools
   - six<2.0,>=1.0
   - colorama
   - prettytable
   - pyusb>=1.0.0b2,<2.0
   - pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1
   - intelhex<3.0,>=2.0
 cbor==1.0.0
 imgtool==1.7.0a1
   - intelhex>=2.2.1
   - click
   - cryptography>=2.4.2
     - cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
       - pycparser
     - six>=1.4.1
   - cbor>=1.0.0
```

I'm using `visualize-requirements` from a tool I wrote called [requirements-tools](https://github.com/Yelp/requirements-tools)

Comment: Do you mean that setuptools is installed together with jsonschema? I have just tried to remove setuptools from my package pyproject.toml file and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'`

Comment: I think you're getting confused about build time (setup_requires / pyproject.toml build-system requires) and installed time (install_requires).  at install time, you're getting unpinned setuptools because it's a transitive dependency without version restrictions

Comment: well, requirements are processed sequentially, so order matters, keeping `setuptools` as the first "requirement" wil always conform to that. @Elephant, I'm testing out your setup.py file

Answer (score 2):

Seems accurate, 50.3.0 is greater than 40.0, less than 51, and not equal to 46.0 or 50.0. You may need to further restrict your requirements. If you know which version you want, just specify that explicitly

EDIT:

I created a fresh venv and checked `pip list`, seems like with a high enough version of pip, setuptools comes at 50.3.0.

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ pip3 list | grep setup
setuptools (20.7.0)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Inside the venv (assuming Python 3.x)

```
$ . vv/bin/activate
(vv) $ pip3 -V
pip 20.2.3 from /home/user/vv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
(vv) $ pip3 list | grep setup
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
setuptools 50.3.0
```

Comment: Restricted to v50.2.0, but still installs 50.3.0 - ```requires = ["setuptools==50.2.0", "pip>=19,!=20.0,!=20.0.1,<21", "wheel"]  # PEP 508 specifications.```

Comment: was it pre-installed? make sure you start fresh with a clean environment. if it's installed using `pip`, maybe try `--force-reinstall` or `-I/--ignore-installed` to ignore previous installations of the same package (`pip3 install --help`)

Comment: No, I cleaned up my virtual environment before.

Comment: @Elephant, check the edit, see if that helps, you may have to force a downgrade (I don't know how to do it off the top)